# Cant see my new version in iTunes connect after upload successful

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I know its duplicate question, I want to update my app and after getting upload successful through the Xcode I can't see the new version...

I want to know how long it usually takes until ill see that? and if after I got upload successful could be another problem why its not upload? if yes what are the problems might be?

**I updated the version and the build number, so its not the issue**

thank you for the help

Comment: You shoud see the build in the Activity tab of your itunes connect app. You will be notified via email when the build is done processing and then you can release the new version.

Comment: @danypata how long is suppose to take?

Comment: Uhm, it should be quite fast, like 10-15 minutes. I've always saw the build in the activity field with the "processing" label on it, after like 10 minutes or so.

Comment: @danypata I can see the build in the activity but on the column of the App Store status its empty, what does it mean?  and now I can see the build in the flight test but it saying missing compliance, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I will post an answer since a comment is to short to answer this.

So the step for the release are:

- Upload a build from Xcode
- Wait for the build to be processed (this can take some time)

  - You will be notified by itunesconnect when the processing is done
  - In this stage the processing can already detect some issues with your app, like missing assets or something like that
  - You can check the status of your build in the activity tab
    [image]
    You won't get any "App Store status" until you actually release it. Now after the processing is done, you can select the build from the "My App -> App Name" in the "Build" section, there is a "+" that, in my opinion is placed very bad.